# Determine an earthquake intensity/magnitude level using ADXL345 and Arduino

Tags: arduino-mega, accelerometer

I want to create a project using Arduino that monitor the Earthquake. I used an ADXL345 Accelerometer to detect if there is an earthquake. I used the Adafruit ADXL345 example to determine a acceleration of x-axis, y-axis and z-axis in terms of m/s^2. I want to used the Japan Meteorological Agency seismic intensity scale to determine the intensity level of the earthquake because it gives the Peak Ground Acceleration. If there is a way to determine the earthquake intensity level using ADXL345?

Comment: Also asked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48365221/accelerometer-using-adxl345-for-earthquake-detection (Jan 21, and already answered)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Copied from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48365221/accelerometer-using-adxl345-for-earthquake-detection]

That sensor is not suitable. It has 13 bit resolution at +-16g full range. That gives you a sensitivity of 0.002g for the lsb. In order to detect an earthquake directly below you, you need approx. a few milli-g ([e.g. see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peak_ground_acceleration)), even less for earthquakes with an epicentre elsewhere.

You want a sensor which is much more sensitive by a factor of 100 and probably with more resolution (better ADC), too.

(And you should have been able to do this quick google-search analysis yourself ;) )

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is the one I brought on online store. But I can used it but I state that this sensor is not precisely detect magnitude.